# TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, html, file, blob

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days. I do not know why it keeps saying that my file is not a type of blob. Any help?

HTML BELOW

```
<form style="padding-top:10px;" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input style="padding-bottom: 20px;" type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="fileValidation(this);">
                                    <div id="responsefromfileupload" value=""></div>
                                </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT BELOW

```
function fileValidation(reader) {

var file = $("input[type=file]").get(0).files[0];
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var filePath = fileInput.value;

// Allowing file type
var allowedExtensions =
    /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;


if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {

$("#responsefromfileupload").replaceWith(`<div style="width: 50%;" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                    This image file type is not accepted!</div>`);
    
}

if (allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
        $("#previewImg").attr("src", reader.result);
        $("#previewImg").attr("margin-left", "25%");
    }

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: try to replace fileValidation(this) to fileValidation(event). In fileValidation rename reader to event and check event.target.files[0] in readAsDataURL. If you create a runnable example, might be easier to get help

Comment: @DraganS I’m very new here, how do I make a runnable example?

Comment: pls check my post - changed your original code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fileValidation(event) {

var file = event.target.files[0];
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var filePath = fileInput.value;

// Allowing file type
var allowedExtensions =
/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;


if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {

$("#responsefromfileupload").replaceWith(`<div style="width: 50%;" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                This image file type is not accepted!</div>`);

}

if (allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function () {
    $("#previewImg").attr("src", reader.result);
    $("#previewImg").attr("margin-left", "25%");
}

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

```html
<form style="padding-top:10px;" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input style="padding-bottom: 20px;" type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="fileValidation(event);">
                                <div id="responsefromfileupload" value=""></div>
                            </form>
```

The template you can use - remove space between < and !--

< !-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

< !-- language: lang-js -->

< !-- language: lang-html -->

< !-- language: lang-css -->

< !-- end snippet -->

Comment: Thank you so much, your var file variable actually fixed it. Do you know why the alert (#responsefromfileupload) only shows up once I select an image twice?

Comment: try to select different files :) guess onchange is not fired 2nd time

Comment: I'm little confused (sorry very new to this world) how can I make onchange fire the first time? or do you know why onclick does the same thing?

Comment: check <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="fileValidation(event);">. There is a onchange attribute. Once you pick a file, assigned handler will be executed. If you pick the same file (as far as I remember) for the 2nd time, "nothing" is changed. Like, you can reset value of it each time after onchange is processed, and then it will execute onchange handler each time.

Comment: But it does not even fire the first time I select a file, it only fires the second time i select a file.

Comment: if you run the example, you will see that it will failed on the first click as I didn't add jquery. So not sure what is the issue on your side.

Comment: Thank you so much for being nice and continuing to reply. So basically, once I select a file once, it will not execute the alert, I have to select a file twice, for even any alert to fire. (If you understood before I apologize.)

Comment: Sorry, can't debug application I can't see :) So, pls press the Run Code Snippet button, click Choose file, select a jpg file. You will see an error message "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", after the 1st click, meaning that your handler is called. Can't help more than that with information you gave me